# trying to perform CRUD, but update not working

Tags: reactjs, crud

NB beginner here. I'm working on a shopping cart react project with rails and performing CRUD operation on user reviews on the page, every operation works well apart from the update method, anything that I'm doing wrong? Here is the code I've written on the Reviews component. Don't mind the cluttered code, I'm still getting used to this.

```
function Renderreview() {
    const [renderReview, setRenderReview] = useState([])
    const [data, setData] = useState({
      review: ""
  
    }) 

    useEffect(() => {
        axios.get('/reviews')
            .then(res => {
                console.log(res)
                setRenderReview(res.data)
            })
            .catch(err => {
                console.log(err)
            })
    }, [])

    function submit(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        axios.post("/reviews",{
            review: data.review,
        })
        .then(res =>{
            console.log(res.data)
        })
    }

    function editReview(id){
       
        axios.put(`/reviews/${id}`,)
        .then(console.log(id))
    }

    function handleDelete(id) {
        axios.delete(`/reviews/${id}`,)
    }
      
      function handle(id){
        const newdata={...data}
        newdata[id.target.id] = id.target.value
        setData(newdata)
        console.log(data)
      }

      function handle2(e){
        const newdata={...renderReview}
        newdata[e.target.id] = e.target.value
        setData(newdata)
        console.log(data)
      }

    return (
        <div className='card1'>

        <div>
            <form className='reviews' onSubmit={(e) => submit(e)}>
                <input onChange={(e)=>handle(e)} id="review" defaultvalue={data.review} placeholder="review" type="text"></input>
                <button>submit review</button>
            </form>
        </div>


            <h2>reviews</h2>
            {renderReview.map((renderReview) => {
                return (
                    <div className='renderedreviews'>{renderReview.review}
                        <button
                            onClick={() => {
                                handleDelete(renderReview.id);
                            }}
                            key={renderReview.review}>
                            Delete
                        </button>

                        <form className='reviews' onSubmit={(id) => editReview(id)}>
                            <input onChange={(id)=>handle2(id)} id="review" defaultvalue={renderReview.review} placeholder="edit" type="text"></input>
                            
                            <button
                            onClick={() => {
                                editReview(renderReview.id);
                            }}
                            key={renderReview.review}>
                            edit
                        </button>
                        </form>
                    </div>
                )
            })}
        </div>
    )
}
```

```
class ReviewsController < ApplicationController
 
def index
  reviews = Review.all
  render json: reviews
end
 
 
 def update
     review = find_review
       if review
         review.update(review_params)
         render json: review
       else
         render json: {error: "Review not found"}, status: :not_found
     end
 end

def destroy
  review =find_review
  if review.destroy
    head :no_content
  else
    render json: {error: review.errors.messages}, status: 422
  end
end

def create
    review = Review.create(review_params)
    render json: review
  end
 
   private
 
def find_review
  Review.find_by(id: params[:id])
end
 
def review_params
  params.permit(:review)
end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

I think your code is missing two things.

1. There is no `value` in your `<input>`

```
<input
    onChange={(id) => handle2(id)}
    id="review"
    defaultvalue={renderReview.review}
    placeholder="edit"
    type="text"
    value={data.review}
></input>
```

3. There is no payload in `editReview`

```
function editReview(id) {
        axios
            .put(`/reviews/${id}`, {
                review: data.review,
            })
            .then(console.log(id));
    }
```

Comment: thanks for the reply, although i don't seem to get you clearly, would you kindly refactor the code?

Comment: Could you check the data before submitting to BE ?

Comment: Oh. When I see this question the first time, there was no backend code. I don't know well about rails. I can help with only the FE.